# Select over 2 select queries

Tags: select

I have two tables: 
**work:**

```
id  w_date        other stuff
1   2017-05-10
1   2017-05-08
3   2017-05-17
```

**home:**

```
id  h_date       other stuff
1   2017-05-01
4   2017-05-06
1   2017-05-14
```

Now I need a query that I get all dates where id is 1.

Something like:

```
Select * 
from (
    select w_date as date 
    from work where id=1
), 
  (select h_date as date from home where id=1)
```

Result should be:

```
id  date
1   2017-05-01
1   2017-05-08
1   2017-05-10
1   2017-05-14
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: You need a [`UNION`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a simple `UNION` query:

```
SELECT id, date
FROM work
WHERE id = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, date
FROM home
WHERE id = 1
ORDER BY date;
```

I've used the `UNION ALL` syntax which return all rows from both source tables.  Leaving the `ALL` keyword out ensures rows that are duplicated in both tables are only returned a single time.

I've added an `ORDER BY` clause at the end of the query to return the list in date ascending order, since your sample data seems to indicate that.

See the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(SQL)#UNION_operator) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this

```
select id,   
       w_date as date 
from work 
where id=1
union all
select id, 
       h_date as date 
from home 
where id=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select ID, date
from home where ID = 1
UNION all
Select ID, date
from work where ID = 1
```

For future posts, try to provide more info, some table and data definitions will go a long way.